# FailOver Config in Wso2 3.2

Tags: wso2, openapi, failover

I am trying to configure Failover (Production and Sandbox) endpoints in Wso2 3.2 API Manager through code.

- I tried doing it with OPENAPI 3.2 swagger file but it didnt work.
- It sets these properties in .xml files in WSO2 configuration directory.

I wanted to pass these Urls through end-user, can some one please help me out here.

Thank you.
Regards,
Priya

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add failover endpoints from the API publisher. Follow this doc. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/design-api/endpoints/high-availability-for-endpoints/#configuring-failover-group-of-endpoints

Comment: Thank you. Can i add these Urls through swagger file upload?

Answer (score 0):

In the APIM-3.2.0 Publisher portal you can configure the failover endpoint by following the below-mentioned steps.

1. Go to the edit view of the API, click Endpoint to view the Endpoint page.
2. Expand Load balance and Failover Configurations.
   [image]
3. In the endpoint type dropdown list select "Failover".
   [image]
4. Provide the production and sandbox URLs for failover endpoints
   [image]

   You need to add at least one failover endpoint as the production and sandbox
   (based on the endpoints that you have specified) endpoints.

   If required, you can specify more than one endpoint by clicking +, and can
   delete the endpoints by clicking on the bin icon.
5. Click SAVE.

Comment: Thank you. Can i add these Urls through swagger file upload?